# Create a Mongodb index for a specific field anywhere in the document

Tags: mongodb

I have a very large collection which I need to be able to quickly search for a specific field.  The problem being that the location of the field could be anywhere in the document.

Is there a way to create an index to the field to be searched without having to do a collection scan?

As an example I might want to find the field '**findField**' with a value of **'34567'** in the structure below:

> [{  fieldOne : {fieldTwo: true; **findField = '12345'**} },
>
> {  fieldThree : {**findField = '23456'**} },
>
> {  fieldFour : {fieldFive: {fieldSix : {**findField : '34567'**}}} }]

Is there a way to create an index for this scenario?

Comment: ...why are your documents designed like this?

Comment: The example was probably a bit extreme as the documents will all have a uniform layout. However, the field I am searching for could exist in multiple locations within the document and I want to know if there is a generic way of querying a field name without having to create an index for each location it could exist.

Comment: Nope, there isn't. You could have a compound index (consisting of all the field names (ie: `{"fieldFixe.fieldSix.findField:1","findField":1}` as one index), and query accordingly.